# How to create hidden folders

Tags: android, image, file, filesystems, sd-card

I want to create some hidden folders like photo hide app and hide the selected image from gallery or camera to  selected hidden folder.i googled a lot but i couldn't find any solution.please find me a solution..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey @jay! If one of the answers was a good response to your question, go ahead and accept it as the correct answer! :)

Answer (score 9):

> *my requirement is when i add files to hidden folder those should not
>   be shown in gallery but hidden folders and files should be shown only
>   in my application..*

1. To create hidden folders or files follow Hamid S. instructions:

   ```
   File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/.Image/");
   file.mkdirs();
   ```
2. To prevent the eg. gallery app from showing pictures within */.Image/*, create the additional (empty) file ***.nomedia***

This prevents media scanner from reading your media files and providing them to other apps through the *MediaStore* content provider. However, if your files are truly private to your app, you should save them in an [app-private directory](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#AccessingExtFiles).

Answer (score 3):

To create hidden folder or file use `Dot (.)` that folder or file name.

Suppose, you want create a folder named `Image` which will be hidden then create as follows...

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/.Image/");
file.mkdirs();
```

Comment: thanks for your kind reply. now i am able to make hidden folders and files but my requirement is when i add files to hidden folder those should not be shown in gallery but hidden folders and files should be shown only in my application..

Comment: this code is working fine in all devices except android 4.4 devices.In android 4.4 devices sdcard (.)folders also visible how can we hide these (.)folder in android 4.4

Answer (score 2):

try this code,

```
String iconsStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.NewFolder";
    File sdIconStorageDir = new File(iconsStoragePath);
    if(!sdIconStorageDir.isDirectory()){
        sdIconStorageDir.mkdirs();//create storage directories, if they don't exist
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try function like..

```
public static void hideFile(File file)
{
        File dstFile = new File(file.getParent(), "." + file.getName());
        file.renameTo(dstFile);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your kind reply. now i am able to make hidden folders and files but my requirement is when i add files to hidden folder those should not be shown in gallery but hidden folders and files should be shown only in my application..

Comment: Its totally new question..post new one,,And if My answer solve your problem you can accept it..

Comment: this code is working fine in all devices except android 4.4 devices.In android 4.4 devices sdcard (.)folders also visible how can we hide these (.)folder in android 4.4

Answer (score 0):

In Android, as well as in most Linux environments, you can create a hidden folder simply by adding a '.' to the front of the folder name.
For example, the folder '.MyFolder' would be hidden.

Comment: thnx for your reply,how to get unhide/visible the  folders and files list in my application and those files and folders should not be visible in device gallery

Comment: By default any hidden files/folders will not be viewable in the gallery. As far as globally unhiding the folder, you would just have to rename it without the '.' in front. If you want to propagate your app with images in the hidden folder, you could just save the path to the hidden folder in SharedPreferences for later use after creating it. As long as you have the proper permissions for accessing files, you will be able to see the files in these saved paths in your app.

Comment: this code is working fine in all devices except android 4.4 devices.In android 4.4 devices sdcard (.)folders also visible how can we hide these (.)folder in android 4.4